# How to execute a Java program from C#?

Tags: c#, java

Wondering if anyone knows a nice way to execute a Java command-line program from C# code at run-time ?

Is it the same as executing native .EXE files ?

Will it run synchronously or asynchronously (which means I may have to wait for the thread to finish to find out the results)

Specifically I would like to call a little utility (which happens to be written in Java) from a web-application on the server side to do some processing on a text file.  I want to wait for it to finish because after the Java program is done processing the text file I want to grab the processed text, and use it within the C# application.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you need finer control than launching an external program, then consider IKVM - http://www.ikvm.net/ - which provides a way to run Java programs inside a .NET world.

Comment: This tool is extremely nice!! I'm sitting in project with a lot of data access from Java and front end app in .Net and solved all my problems!

Comment: anyone knows if this project is dead? 2012 seems to be the last update and only v7... not v8

Comment: The project is confirmed [dead](http://weblog.ikvm.net/2017/04/21/TheEndOfIKVMNET.aspx) by the lead developer

Comment: @Alexander No, he just don't want to work on it anymore.  If anybody else wants to, they can.  Apparently none do.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen usually this kind of situation is considered dead project...

Comment: @XenoAmess Yes, if nobody picks it up.  For _this_ particular project I was actually expecting one or more businesses to pick it up because it was important to them.   Apparently this actually happened:  https://www.windwardstudios.com/blog/ikvm-is-alive-well

Answer (score 26):

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", "-jar app.jar")
                      {
                          CreateNoWindow = true,
                          UseShellExecute = false
                      };
Process proc;

if ((proc = Process.Start(processInfo)) == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("??");
}

proc.WaitForExit();
int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
proc.Close();
```

Answer (score 12):

It's the same as executing native .EXE files, only that the executable you will have to execute is the JVM itself (java.exe).

So, inside your C# code call:

> java.exe -jar nameofyourjavaprogram.jar

And you should be fine.

If you don't have your java program on a JAR library, just make the JVM launch with all the parameters you need.

Comment: Also note there is a DLL you can invoke in case you need something back from the JVM.

Answer (score 7):

I added a couple of lines to the above solution.  I wanted to call a Web Service from a Silverlight app that process some files using java on the server.  The above solution is helpful but I modified a little bit so that it works since calling via a web service is a little bit trickier.  Now you have the right tool for the job, C# when appropriate, Java when C# cannot solve the problem.  It's always good to know more than just one way of doing things.  Now my Web Service created in .Net can talk to Java.

```
private void Merge(string strPath)
{
  var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_24\\binjava.exe", "-jar app.jar")
  {
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     UseShellExecute = false
  };

  processInfo.WorkingDirectory = strPath; // this is where your jar file is.
  Process proc;

  if ((proc = Process.Start(processInfo)) == null)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("??");
  }

  proc.WaitForExit();
  int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
  proc.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Will it run synchronously or asynchronously

It will run asynchronously if you have enough cores, otherwise it run independently, but your thread will have to context switch so the other program will run.  Either way its not something you should need to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would run faster if you use [jni4net - C#/Java bridge](http://jni4net.sf.net)

Answer (score 2):

Just for the completeness:
When lauching a Swing jar from C# I found this detail: if you don't set the working directory in the ProcessStartInfo object, your shiny Swing app will launch... **but with no icons and no images**!!

This is the minimal working code copied from the answers here and elsewhere on SO (works for me: Java 1.8 on Win7, mi images and icons are in a subfolder of the workingDirectory):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", " -jar \"C:\\Program Files\\Installed Shiny Swing jar app\\Myjar.jar\"");
psi.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\Installed Shiny Swing jar app\\"; // Do not miss this line so you awesome Swing app will show default java icon and no images
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```