# Running a Java (.jar) app inside a C# app

Tags: c#, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use a .jar java library API in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512124/use-a-jar-java-library-api-in-c)

I have a jar file I want to run in a C# application, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512124/use-a-jar-java-library-api-in-c

Comment: [How to execute a Java program from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873809/how-to-execute-a-java-program-from-c)

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [ikvmc.exe](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) compiler to generate a .NET assembly from this `.jar`:

```
ikvmc.exe -target:library -out:Foo.dll Foo.jar
```

This will generate `Foo.dll`. From now on you know what to do with the managed `Foo.dll` assembly.

Comment: The op says he wants to run the .jar file, not use it as a library.

Comment: @Marcelo, what makes you think that the .jar contains a `main` method? Of course if this was the case the OP could read the documentation of the article I have linked to in my answer and use `ikvmc.exe -target:exe -out:Foo.exe Foo.jar` and then run `Foo.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IKVM`](http://www.ikvm.net/).

From the [Uses for IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/uses.html) page:

> **Use Java libraries in your .NET applications**
>
> IKVM.NET includes ikvmc, a Java bytecode to .NET IL translator. If you have a Java library that you would like to use in a .NET application, run ikvmc -target:library mylib.jar to create mylib.dll.
>
> For example, the Apache FOP project is an open source XSL-FO processor written in Java that is widely used to generate PDF documents from XML source. With IKVM.NET technology, Apache FOP can be used by any .NET application.

Comment: The op says he wants to run the .jar file, not use it as a library.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line :

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("java -jar filename.jar");

If you want these java and c# to interact with each other use shared file or socket programming

Note you need to configure java in ur system.