# How to run Java (a JAR file) from C#?

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio, c#-4.0, jar

I want to create a wrapper for this client for a game but it's in Java. How would I run the .jar file in C#?

Comment: You should look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873809/how-to-execute-a-java-program-from-c

Comment: The link provided by scrappedcola describes how to *launch a Java process* from C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked into [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300836%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to run the appropriate `java -jar file.jar` command? You might want to add some fancy logic to try and ensure a `java` is indeed available on the system, but that shouldn't be too hard...

Answer (score 1):

One option is [JuggerNET](http://www.codemesh.com/products/juggernet/) by CodeMesh, which generates .NET wrappers for Java APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper is called wrapper because it wraps the jar file and starts it using a virtual machine. There are also some wrappers that already contain the VM in the exe file.

You do not need to write such a wrapper by yourself, these are already. One powerful and free wrapper is [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).