# Visual C++/C# launching Java

Tags: java, launching-application

I am developing a Java Game and it will be ran as an Application (Not an Applet), so I would like to make a window/.exe to launch before hand, which has options (E.g. "Play"), although I am completely unsure how to do this.

I would like it to run in the same window as the C++/C# window, but if it cannot and runs by itself, that is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by C++/C# window?

Comment: Visual C++ window, so for example a window with a button on it saying "Play". @HunterMcMillen

Comment: one of java's strengths is that you can run it in different systems, at the cost of some speed. if you compile it to an exe (there are compilers that generate native code out there) you loose this benefit.

Comment: @vulkanino I'm not looking to make the Java file itself an exe, I'm looking to make an exe that launches the Java .jar itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a Java program from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873809/how-to-execute-a-java-program-from-c)

Comment: Why the Visual c++ window with button "play", why not just launch the game immediately?

Comment: @OlliM As it won't just have play, it'll have more configurable options for the game play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to use JNI, but not for Java to call "native" code, for the native code to bootstrap a JVM.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>

JNIEnv* create_vm() {
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    /* There is a new JNI_VERSION_1_4, but it doesn't add anything for the purposes of our example. */
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\\projects\\local\\inonit\\classes";
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);
    return env;
}

void invoke_class(JNIEnv* env) {
    jclass helloWorldClass;
    jmethodID mainMethod;
    jobjectArray applicationArgs;
    jstring applicationArg0;

    helloWorldClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "example/jni/InvocationHelloWorld");

    mainMethod = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, helloWorldClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    applicationArgs = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 1, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String"), NULL);
    applicationArg0 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "From-C-program");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, applicationArgs, 0, applicationArg0);

    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, helloWorldClass, mainMethod, applicationArgs);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    JNIEnv* env = create_vm();
    invoke_class( env );
}
```

is one way of doing it, [as detailed here](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/c.html).

There are numerous tools which do nothing other than build the executable launcher.  One such project (no experience with it, I use JNI directly) [is JSmooth](http://freecode.com/projects/jsmooth). Look to [Freecode](http://freecode.com/) (formerly freshmeat) and the like for others.

The big differences come into play when you decide you need to do more checking of the environment for proper initialization of latter JVMs, and how much verification you wish to undergo as you marshal the command line parameters from one environment to the next.

Comment: These tools are a better idea than what I commented, just use them and you're done.

Comment: This code looks like what I'm looking for. Although could you explain it a little more? It's quite confusing to me, I haven't had much experience with the C family before.

Comment: There are C++ versions of it out there, if you shop around.  Basically, it uses `<jni.h>` to reference a number of C / C++ functions, and the "jni shared object library" which contains an interface into the Java world.  `create_vm(...)` is a function you write to call the jni function `JNI_CreateVM(...)`  The end result is to return a pointer to a "java environment" which allows the rest of the C / C++ code to send information to the JVM.  When creating a JVM in this manner, the "main class" isn't loaded for you, so you have to do that manually, via `invoke_class`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a window for the exe? Wouldn't it just be enough to have an exe that launches the java runtime. Essentially a bat file with "java -jar mygame.jar", but as an exe?

That will be really easy to implement - getting the java game to run inside the same window would be much more difficult.

Comment: I guess that would be fine, what about an EXE which launches a visual window with a "Play" button, which then launches the bat file? Is that possible?

Comment: Everything is possible, but I don't see why you would want that? It seems to me that the "Play" button should be part of the game -> implemented in java like the rest of the game. The exe should only be a thin wrapper to make launching the game easier for users.

Comment: Again, it's just so that I can show and messages from a news feed, and display different options that affect the game play.

Comment: Just a .bat or .cmd file is what a lot of small open source programs use - really the simplest option.

Comment: Okay, could you please explain to me how to do this? I will try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: Is there a reason that the game options and news feed would be implemented in a different language than the game? Just seems like extra complexity without a reason. If you decide to go that way, the link above by @vulcanino has the implementation details.

Comment: I think taking a look at the method you describe and the post above will give me a better understanding. And I think it would be more difficult to do in Java, but that's just me.

Comment: create text file named <game_name>.cmd, inside it type:
java -jar <game_name>.jar

Comment: Is there not a way to make an EXE for it? So I can assign my own icon, etc.

Comment: Check the links by Edwin Buck, they are an easier way to create the exe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system function like that system("java -jar game.jar");

Comment: I've been advised not to use this by a good bunch of programmers.

Comment: use the jni is the another way, but i think is so complicated.