# Launch jar from C#

Tags: c#, jar, minecraft

How do I start a java application from a C# application?

I'm working on a minecraft launcher. Is there a general method to start any jar from a C# application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873809/how-to-execute-a-java-program-from-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129989/how-to-call-java-code-from-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start the jar file as a new process:

```
string appData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA");

Process.Start(@"java",
  @"-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp """ + appData + @"\.minecraft\bin\*"" -Djava.library.path=""" + appData + @"\.minecraft\bin\natives"" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft");
```

This assumes `java` is in your `PATH` (which happens by default when java is installed). If not, use the absolute path to java.

This is starting the game directly - you can use the minecraft launcher if the user told you where they put it. On windows, that's an exe, so you can start it directly.

Also, APPDATA is a window's variable. For linux, the path is in `$HOME`, or `~/`. Also, the params aren't quite the same. Assuming your users will run your app with Mono for linux (or apple). I don't have Mono handy to test the options for you, but you can use

```
public static bool IsLinux
{
    get
    {
        int p = (int) Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
        return (p == 4) || (p == 6) || (p == 128);
    }
}
```

To help you select the correct start path. The above code was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116977/c-sharp-how-to-check-the-os-version-at-runtime-e-g-windows-or-linux-without-usi). I note that the property in the sample above is called `IsLinux`, yet the quote from Mono docs says `6` is for Mac OS X. This leads me to believe the property should actually be called `IsUnix` (as apple fanatics continue to preach such is the case though apple is as much unix as windows is dos). I don't have macware on hand to test this, I leave that to the student.

Comment: Wait, I thought it would be like string appData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("%APPDATA%"); to go into the appdata folder

Comment: @Matthewj nope, the %'s are just used on the command line to trigger the var lookup, the var name is just appdata.

Comment: Alright, so I tried out the code and it opens a java command promp and after a few seconds it closes but minecraft doesnt open.

Comment: @Matthewj it works for me. I tested before I posted. Linux or windows? We should chat about this out-of-comments and work it out for you. We can use SO chat (or irc, I'm always in minecrafthelp on esper).