# Starting a Jar file using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, java, system.diagnostics

I have a jar file which I want to run from within C#.

Here's what I have so far:

```
clientProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"java -jar C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\myJarFile.jar";
            clientProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "[Something]";

            clientProcess.Start();
            clientProcess.WaitForExit();

            int exitCode = clientProcess.ExitCode;
```

Unfortunatly I get "System could not find specified file", which makes sense since its not a file its a command.

I've seen code online which tells you to use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("java -jar myprog.jar");
```

However I need the return codes AND I need to wait for it to exit.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried
`clientProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\myJarFile.jar";` ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a Java program from C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873809/how-to-execute-a-java-program-from-c)

Comment: @yogi - I did , it failed silently.

Comment: @Filburt - I disagree. My problem is more specific. The answer to just running it is to use the code I've put at the bottom. However I want to run it, wait until its done and get the exit code - which is where the issue starts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally solved it. The filename has to be java and the arguments has to contain the location of the jar file (and anything arguments you want to pass that)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process clientProcess = new Process();
clientProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
clientProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-jar "+ jarPath +" " + argumentsFortheJarFile;
clientProcess.Start();
clientProcess.WaitForExit();   
int code = clientProcess.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to remove the `!= 0)` and the `;` on the end :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set environment variable `Path` of `java.exe` executable or specify the full path of `java.exe`.

```
 ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe",@"-jar C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\myJarFile.jar");
 Process.Start(ps);
```

Comment: And how would I get the return code , or block until its finished?