# Execute a java console app in a seperate location with class path (cp)

Tags: java, c#, process, system.diagnostics

I have a requirement to execute a `.jar` file in another directory. Following is the code I attempted to perform this task,

```
        try
        {

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"java cp D:\nfc\nfctools-examples-M9\nfctools-examples-M9\src\main\java\nfctools-examples.jar";//, @"-cp nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo");
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();
            String s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "data = " + s;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

But I get the error `The system cannot find the file specified error`. I did the task referring to the posts,

- [Starting a Jar file using System.Diagnostics.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997915/starting-a-jar-file-using-system-diagnostics-process)
- [Execute Jar file from C sharp code and get return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475944/execute-jar-file-from-c-sharp-code-and-get-return-value)

I would be really grateful if you experts could assist me in fixing this error. Thank you very much :)

**Edit**

the path `org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo` is in `D:\nfc\nfctools-examples-M9\nfctools-examples-M9\src\main\java\`.

The folder stucture is,

```
D:\
    nfc\
        nfctools-examples-M9\
            nfctools-examples-M9\
                src\
                    main\
                        java\
                            *nfctools-examples.jar
                            |org\
                            |   nfctools\
                            |       examples\
                            |           hce\
                            |               HceDemo.java
```

The * represents the .jar file that needs to be executed and the pipe symbol represents the class path `cp` shown by `org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo`.

This execution is done in command prompt via `java -cp nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo` from within the `D:\nfc\nfctools-examples-M9\nfctools-examples-M9\src\main\java\` folder.

**My requirement** is to perform the execution via `C#` and obtain the result of the `jar` file execution to a `textbox`.

Answer (score 1):

The file specified by FileName must exist. Don't add any arguments to this property. Therefore, you have to turn your code into this:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"java";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"cp D:\nfc\nfctools-examples-M9\nfctools-examples-M9\src\main\java\nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo";
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir..but the same error still occurs

Comment: Then either specify the full path to the java.exe file or make sure, that the path to the java.exe file is part of your PATH variable

Comment: The thing is, if I run this command `java -cp D:\nfc\nfctools-examples-M9\nfctools-examples-M9\src\main\java\nfctools-examples.jar org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo` it works fine

Comment: Sir I did not get what you said..can you please clarify?