# Process Start Wont Work Cmd Window C#

Tags: c#, shell, cmd, process, command

I am working on a visual studio 2017 Project on C# and i tried to use the code Process Start. But when i tried it the command did not work cmd window opened but it did not write any command on the Window. What can i do ?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("cmd", "command");
}
```

Comment: Define `the command did not work`. _The above code worked fine for me - it opened up a command prompt._

Comment: so it did not applied the command as Like

Example Cmd
Cmd> command

Comment: it did not run the command on the window

Comment: im trying to run this command 
java - cp.\bin\minecraft.jar;.\bin\lwjgl.jar;.\bin\lwjgl_util.jar; -Djava.library.path =.\bin\natives net.minecraft.client.Minecraft

Comment: See the link I provided earlier. Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/32124794/34092 . Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/11030976/34092 .

Comment: so can you send me the code for it because in the link there is  3 or 4 codes commented by people and you can you give me the right one

Comment: If there are multiple commands they can be separated by "&" as shown in my example below.

Comment: :) Thanks for help dude you helped me alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c command & pause");
```

I added the & pause so you can see the window stay up.

If you don't want the window to show at all.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo( "cmd", "/c command" );
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start( info );
```

Comment: Thankyou dude :)

Comment: If an answer or comment helps you can upvote and/or select it as an answer.

Comment: so dude i have a question in the end i want to add this to the command before pause but how is that gonna happen ? label3.Text like

Comment: You probably don't need to keep the pause.  But I'm also not understanding what you are asking.

Comment: k then still Thanks

Comment: I have another question? how can i hide the cmd ? when it launches ? Thx

Comment: I updated the answer.