# Why is this Command Prompt Script not running in C#?

Tags: c#, command-prompt, batch-processing

I need to run a bunch of commands in C# in order for my program to run correctly. Previously, this script ran flawlessly and I used to get the desired output my program needs in order to compile and run correctly.

This is the script I have currently

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C mkdir C:\IL & del Output.il & cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools & ildasm /out=C:\IL\Output.il " + filePath;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmd.Start();
```

Filepath is a parameter I pass back to this method. This parameter contains the file's URL.

When the filepath is loaded into the application now, this set of commands does not run whatsoever. There is no output file or anything. However, these commands run when I enter them manually into Command Prompt.

I've tried this process from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928712/process-start-wont-work-cmd-window-c-sharp) answer, and implemented the following code to try and get this batch file to work.

```
ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo( "cmd",  @"/C mkdir C:\IL & del Output.il & cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools & ildasm /out=C:\IL\Output.il" + filePath );
cmd.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start( cmd );
```

The above method hasn't worked out, and the other posts on here have the same code as my own script, which doesn't help at all.

Is there anything wrong with my script? Or is there a setting that I can enable in Visual Studio?

Thanks for viewing

Comment: Try to put your file path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft    SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools` into quotes

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski you don't need to quote the path after `cd`. Run `cd /?` and you'll see *CHDIR command does not treat spaces as delimiters, so it is possible to CD into a subdirectory name that contains a space without surrounding
the name with quotes.* but `filePath` needs to be quoted if it contains spaces

Comment: @phuclv I cannot thank you enough. Putting filePath in quotes solved the issue. The program runs just fine now.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, just out of curiosity: why don’t you do the file system stuff directly in your C# code and then use `Process.Start` only to call `ildasm` without the redirection through `cmd`?

Comment: I would have loved to just call ildasm through Process.Start, but my lead developer on this project insists on breaking down the command process into step by step lines to "help speed up and optimize debugging". If I had my way, I would have done just that.