# Execute Jar file from C sharp code and get return value

Tags: c#, java

Just I want to execute the Jar file from C sharp code and get return values from jar. Is it possible?

If so give me the sample code.

I tried following thing,

```
            string path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Desktop";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar \"" + path + "\\simple.jar\"";
            process.Start();
            String s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

here simple.jar has main method which will take the arguements and prints the passed arguemnets in console, otherwise it prints no arguements in console.
I tried above code in this line(String s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();) able to read the console values.

But I want to execute a method by passing values in jar and method will return me hashmap (collection) values(I don't know it is possible or not).
Please give me suggestions on this.

Comment: You can run it as a command line program, like any other command line program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873809/how-to-execute-a-java-program-from-c covers this i think.

Answer (score 7):

To execute a jar file in the command line use `java.exe -jar <jar_name>`.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) to see how do you execute a command line program and get its output in `C#`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar C:\\FileLocal\\file.jar";
        myProcess.Start();
```