# Call a Java JAR file from Kofax TotalAgility (KTA)

Tags: kofax

I have a BPMN for document management in KTA. The steps are the following :

- Create a TIFF file (scan)
- Classify document
- Convert to PDF
- ...
- Electronic signature with chambersign
- etc.

[image]

My issue is the following : 
I was asked to develop a Java module in order to get the documents that are processed, to make electronic signature and to send it back to KTA. I just don't know how KTA can call my JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a .NET wrapper DLL and then call said library in a .NET Activity. Simply calling a JAR from .NET and getting data back is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475944/execute-jar-file-from-c-sharp-code-and-get-return-value), but it might get more complicated that that (since you mentioned sending the document back to KTA).

A possible solution would be to have your JAR simply sign a document that's located on the disk (e.g. `c:\in\123.pdf`). The .NET wrapper would then download the PDF from KTA's repository, call your JAR, and then upload the updated file again. You can use the `GetDocument` method from `CaptureDocumentService` to retrieve a file, [here's some code](https://www.theorycrafter.org/quipu/writing-a-download-handler-for-kta/) to get you started.

Comment: thats great... In fact I also discovered that it was also possible to put in a BPMN process C# code and even JavaScript. It will make my life easier. I will post how I put the code in KTA ...